# Add a textbox to the firefox browser toolbar

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

I am trying to add a textbox that will navigate to a link formulated by adding whatever the user types into it to a preset url and opening a new tab to visit it.However, I did not find informations regarding adding textboxes to the firefox browser toolbar on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: Could you just look into the search engine stuff? After all that's pretty much what it does.

Comment: I used python & webkit. https://rk.edu.pl/en/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/ Then I was able to create my own combobox and populate it with my data I wanted to look up. Since converted to qt5. Had to change a lot: change from QtWebKit to QtWebEngine

Comment: @Seth Yes that is a viable and functional but unpreferred alternative in my case